# Store more than 8000 characters in a string using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create one html table with column in SQL Server which having more than 8000 characters. So `varchar(Max)` store only 8000 so any solution..

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: `varchar(max)` supports more than 1,000,000,000 characters in all currently supported versions of SQL Server.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      10.50.1600.1

Comment: `varchar(max)` stores **2 BILLION** characters - enough to hold over 100 copies of Leo Tolstoj's "War and Peace" - in a single column! Enough even for you, I'm sure ...

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comments `VARCHAR(MAX)` can hold far more characters than your fingertips would allow you to bash out. Bear in mind if you `PRINT` a `VARCHAR(MAX)` variable, it will only print out the *first* 8000 characters (as default), since this is the limit for the `PRINT` function.

EDIT: Expanding on that, you can pass the character position to `PRINT` and it will display 8000 characters from that position, so a simple while loop would be sufficient to display the entirety of the variable.